# Installing 18.04 LTS and the program can't see my SCSI partitions

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, raid, disk, scsi

I am installing 18.04 LTS on my server with a CD. I have a second-hand HP ProLiant DL360 G5 server and I had 17.04 on it. I erased the system to load 18.04 LTS on it and I have two RAID 0 SAS partitions on it.

I can't seem to get it to see my SCSI partitions. What can I do?

Comment: Thanks, I have a second hand HP ProLiant DL360 G5 severer  I had 17.04 on it. I erased the system to load 18.04 on it and I have two RAID 0 SAS partitions on it.